# cannot inherit from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

My code is as follows

```
class BaseClass<T> where T : class
{
    class DerivedClass<U, V>
        where U : class
        where V : U
    {
        BaseClass<V> _base;
    }

}
```

**error:** The type 'V' must be reference type.

Isn't 'V' here of type class ??

Comment: Not smart enough, indeed, and too costly to implement. Eric Lippert explains: http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by adding a `class` constraint to the `V` type parameter:

```
class BaseClass<T> where T : class
{
    class DerivedClass<U, V>
        where U : class
        where V : class, U
    {
        BaseClass<V> _base;
    }
}
```

For an explanation, see from [Eric Lippert's article](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/) (as commented above by [Willem van Rumpt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269392/willem-van-rumpt)).

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't 'V' here of type class ??

No it is not. `V` could be of `System.ValueType` or any enum, or any `ValueType`.

Your constraint just says that `V` should be derived from `U` where as `U` is class. It doesn't says that `V` should be a class.

For example the following is perfectly valid, which contradicts with the constraint `where T : class`.

```
DerivedClass<object, DateTimeKind> derived;
```

So you need to add `where V : class` also.

Eric Lippert has blogged [the very same question](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation.aspx).